# Jhipster spring production profile

Tags: spring, jhipster

I have generated an spring API using jhipster.
Right now I have two profile: application.yml and application-dev.yml

application.yml is for production but there is no configuration for database like in application-dev.yml.

Is this normal or from what takes this configuration for production?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`application.yml` contains the properties for default profile not for production, this is where you put the common properties. The production properties are in `application-prod.yml` and usually should be externalized (i.e. not included in the jar)